# Change a string text if another contains a certain value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got this html code:

```
<p class="day-left">
   <span style="color: #000" id="countdown2"></span> 
   <span id="days">days</span> to <strong>the EVENT</strong>!
</p>
```

The output is:

```
3 days to the EVENT.
```

The countdown 2 is running a function that calculate the days left.

I want when the span countdown2 is = 1, the text of span days change to "day", not "days".

I tryed this code, but not worked:

```
if ($('span#countdown2:contains("<span style="color: #000" id="countdown2">1</span>")').length > 0) {
            $("#days").write("day");
        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: `if ($('#countdown2').text() === '1') {
   $('#days').text('day')
 }`

Comment: How do you change the #countdown2 value?   At the same time as changing that, change #days:  `$("#days").text("day" + (countdown === 1 ? "" : "s"))`

Comment: But jQuery doesn't *have* a [`write()`](https://api.jquery.com/write) method. Are there any errors in your console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want something like this?

```js
const countdown2 = document.getElementById("countdown2");
const days = document.getElementById("days");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  countdown2.textContent = +countdown2.textContent - 1;
  
  // you need these codes
  if (+countdown2.textContent < 2) {
    days.textContent = "day";
  }
  //
  
});
```

```html
<button>decrease</button>

<p class="day-left">
   <span style="color: #000" id="countdown2">4</span> 
   <span id="days">days</span> to <strong>the EVENT</strong>!
</p>
```

Comment: thanks mate! what means that plus before countdown2?

Comment: @LucasFernandes that `+` convert `string` to `number`

Answer (score 1):

This helps ?

```js
const days = document.getElementById("days")
const counter = document.getElementById("countdown2")
let count = 10

window.onload = () => {
  counter.innerText = count

  this.interval =
    setInterval(() => {
      count--
      counter.innerText = count
      days.innerText = count === 1 ? "day" : "days"
      if (count <= 0) clearInterval(this.interval)
    }, 1000)

}
```

```html
<p class="day-left">
  <span style="color: #000" id="countdown2"></span>
  <span id="days">days</span> to <strong>the EVENT</strong>!
</p>
```